# How to close a pop up window and redirect the url to parent page?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, facebook

I have created a django app. I have implemented a facebook login along with a django login for my app. On clicking the facebook login button, an outh login page pop ups and i able to login bu giving username and password there. But even after signing in, that pop up is not closing, and the new url to be showed after sign in is showed in that same pop up page. The same login page(parent page) for django app stays at the back during this time. Is there a way to close the pop up page once the user is logged in , and the corresponding url redirection to be made in the parent page.? Please help me to solve this , as i am quite new to programming. Also please tell me what all codes i should post here to give you a better idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call this JS in popup page:

```
window.opener.location.href = "http://some/new/location";
window.close();
```

Comment: that was perfect. you guys really help newbies like me to learn..thanks a lot :)